# Rewriting URL based on hostname

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

Is it possible to use .htaccess file to rewrite this:

http://customer1.com/app/assets/css

into this:

http://customer1.com/app/customers/customer1/assets/css?

If it is then how?

EDIT: The goal is to avoid any updates to .htaccess when a new customer is added
EDIT2:

I see that my question has been too vague. I have a CMS that is being used for lots of different customers (www.foo.com, www.bar.com, www.somerandomname.com). Each customer has it's unique files (design, uploads) in a directory /data/www/cms/customers/XXXXXX/ where XXXXXX is the name of the customer. Apache config file has default DocumentRoot set on /data/www/cms/.

What I'm trying to do is to have the URL http://www.foo.com/app/assets/css/bg.png to return a file from the given customers data directory, i.e. /data/www/cms/app/customers/foo.com/assets/css/bg.png.

Comment: A little more detail - is this a one off to aid a content move, or is it going to be a part of daily use so to speak.

Also, just one site or do you want something generic to apply everywhere?

Comment: @Dan A part of daily use. Just one site.

Comment: Will the destination be `/data/www/cms/app/customers/foo.com/assets/css/bg.png` with foo**.com** or only "foo" without the ".com" (= is this a mistake or not)? This is important for the rewrite rule I may answer.

Comment: Real life example: /data/www/sisuhaldus/clients/riito_ee/galleries/4/pics/raua1.jpg, where riito_ee is a particular customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about `.htaccess` file but I'm pretty sure this would work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} customer([0-9]+)\.com
RewriteRule ^/app/(.*) /app/customers/customer%1/$1 [QSA]
```

---

Explanation:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} customer([0-9]+)\.com
```

will put in the variable '`%1`' the customer number i.e. '`1`'

```
RewriteRule ^/app/(.*) /app/customers/customer%1/$1 [QSA]
```

Means: if the path *begins* with '`/app/`' then rewrite it to `/app/customers/customer` and add the variable '`%1`' (i.e. '`1`' in our example) so it should work with what you're asking for: rewrite to `http://customer1.com/app/customers/customer1/`.

I'm sorry but your question is not really precise, and you should either giver more examples, or be more specific to what you want to do, but I did my best to help you.

You may use the `RewriteMap` directive as well.
Imagine you put all your clients websites and the right directories in it like this:

```
alsace                     1   
aquitaine                  2   
auvergne                   3   
basse-normandie            4   
bourgogne                  5   
bretagne                   6   
centre                     7   
champagne-ardenne          8   
corse                      9   
franche-comte              10  
haute-normandie            11
```

then I use a RewriteRule like this:

```
RewriteMap mapregions dbm:/web/htdocs/maps/regions.map
RewriteRule ^/region/(.*)/$ /handle_regions.php \
  [NC,E=REGION:${mapregions:$1|notfound}]
```

So what it does is basically: if you ask for an url like `/region/(.*)/` it redirects to `/handle_regions.php` and sets an environment variable `REGION`
Then I just check if it was found: if not, I stop:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REGION} notfound
# "not found" = 404 :
RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]
```

And then here you are. I'm sorry but with all the things I've just said, you have enough material to solve your problem. I don't have the time to do all the stuff for you, sorry man, I did the best I could to help you... and I hope this helps!

Comment: I updated the question and added more information.

Comment: Please update this answer to correspond to my comment under the question?

Comment: I've updated it! No offense, but I don't have the time to do all the stuff for you, sorry man, I did the best I could to help you... and I hope this helps!

Comment: That's OK. That's more than enough for me. Thank you. I left this previous comment only to be sure you knew that I had answered your comment under the question part, as I wasn't sure you get notifications when it's not your answer and you are not the first commenter (This would be really useful: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99261/tell-the-user-who-will-be-notified-of-a-comment)

Comment: You welcome ;) !

Answer (score -1):

That will be something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} !^customer1\.com\/app\/$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://customer1.com/app/customers/customer1/$1
```

Comment: `HTTP_HOST` is just the hostname - need to handle the `/app` match in the `RewriteRule` (and not unintentionally capture that part of the URL).

Comment: Can I use %{http_host} in rewriting so that I wouldn't have to create a separate Rewrite rules for each and every customer?

Comment: I'm sorry but your RewriteRule is not correct (it will do a real redirect (301) because when you write `http://` in a rewrite rule it does a *real* 301 whatever the rule is).